# Can I pre-allocate arrays of objects?

Tags: javascript

How can I create a preallocated array of 'Myobject' ???
I know you can do :

```
var a = new array(100);
```

By now you can only do :

```
var a = new array();
a.push (new Myobject()); (100 times)
```

I'd like to do  :

```
var a = new array(Mobject,100)
```

(or something similar)
Is it possible ? 
Are going to be efficient ? TH.

Comment: All elements with reference to the same object or new objects?

Comment: In any case you'll have to loop, explicitly or not. [Look for this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can use the `Array` function to create an already filled array :

```
var a = Array.apply(0,Array(100)).map(function() { return new Myobject() });
```

Note that :

- it's not clearer than a simple `for` loop
- it's not faster*

**Edit in 2018:** Now it's simpler:

```
var a = Array(100).fill().map(()=>new Myobject);
```

Comment: Then ...map is or not faster than simple loop ?

Comment: @Zougen Moriver : what is your opinion map or not map ? And your idea could be used width some array.prototype extend , couldn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It uses an implicit loop and you would need to shim it for older browsers, but I think it's kinda cool:

<del>`var a = new Array(100).map(function() {return new Myobject();});`</del>

EDIT: Or it would be cool if it worked =/ Never mind.

```
for( var a=[], i=0; i<100; i++) a[i] = new Myobject();
```

Comment: @dystroy Just realised that =/ Bugger.

Comment: Using the `Array` function is tricky, I answered to show how it can (didn't say "should") be done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reusable function using a simple loop, and doesn't rely on `map` availability:

```
function createPrefilled(obj, len) {
    var a = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        a.push(new obj());
    }
    return a;
}
```

Example usage:

```
var a = createPrefilled(Mobject, 100);
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/UF29d/).**